# How to implement WriteHexBytes using two subroutines to work?

Tags: assembly, subroutine

Can anyone help with me how do Load the two sectors I need, then loop through the machine code of the functions passing each byte to the writeHexByte. Then use WriteHexBytes subroutine to display 2 other subroutine's machine code.

Each subroutine is in a different sector, and each each sector is 512 bytes (0x200), then place them that far apart when loading them. e.g. the boot sector is at 0x7c00, so the next sector could be placed at 0x7e00.  I need **WriteHexBytes subroutine** to display 2 of the other subroutine's machine code.

Right now the code is displaying 0, 1, 3 before implementing WriteHexBytes

This lab is using macros.

```
    # Macro definition
.macro convertHexNibble register
push \register
    cmpb $10, \register
    jl 1f
    # process here is >=10
    add $0x37, \register
    jmp 2f  
    # process here is <=10
    1:
    add $0x30, \register    
    2:
    # expect the register to now be the ascii code
    pop \register
.endm

.macro displayChar character color
mov $0x09, %ah
mov \character, %al  
mov $0x00, %bh 
mov \color, %bl 
mov $0x01, %cx
int $0x10
.endm

# set defualts values to move cursor off screen
.macro moveCursor row = $0xff column = $0xff
push %bx
push %dx
mov $0x02, %ah # ah = 02h moves the cursor row 2 col 2
mov $0x00, %bh # bh = 0 page
mov \row, %dh 
mov \column, %dl # dl=1
int $0x10
pop %dx
pop %bx
.endm
# this is hardcode to read 3 sectors into 7e00
.macro readSector n
mov $0x02, %ah
mov \n, %al
mov $0x00, %ch
mov $0x02, %cl
mov $0x80, %dl
mov $0x00, %dh
mov $0x7e00, %bx
int $0x13
.endm

# The main boot processing code
.code16
.text
.global _start
_start:

readSector $4 # convert to subroutine

push $0x30
push $0xe3
call displayChar
add $4, %sp #clear 2 parameters that we pushed (2 bytes each)

push $0x05
push $0x10
call moveCursor
add $4, %sp

push $0x31
push $0xe3
call displayChar
add $4, %sp #clear 2 parameters that we pushed (2 bytes each)

push $0x07
push $0x07
push $0x03
call writeHexByte
add $6, %sp

push $0x04
call writeHexByte
add $2, %sp

cli # clear interrupts
hlt
#put subroutine version of readSector here
. = _start + 510
.byte 0x55
.byte 0xAA
#end of boot sector

# this is in sector 2 
#set defualts values to move cursor off screen
moveCursor: # row = $0xff column = $0xff
.equ row, 6
.equ col, 4
push %bp
mov %sp, %bp #sets up stack frame
push %bx
push %dx
mov $0x02, %ah 
mov $0x00, %bh 
mov row(%bp), %dh 
mov col(%bp), %dl 
int $0x10
pop %dx
pop %bx
pop %bp # restores the callers stack frame
ret

. = moveCursor + 512

# this is in sector 3
displayChar: # character color
.equ character, 6
.equ color, 4
push %bp
mov %sp, %bp #sets up stack frame
push %bx
push %cx
mov $0x09, %ah
mov character(%bp), %al #character  
mov $0x00, %bh 
mov color(%bp), %bl #color 
mov $0x01, %cx
int $0x10
pop %cx
pop %bx
pop %bp # restores the callers stack frame
ret
. = displayChar + 512 

# This is sector 4
writeHexByte:
.equ byte, 4
.equ row, 6
.equ col, 8
push %bp
mov %sp, %bp #stack up frame

push row(%bp)
push col (%bp)
call moveCursor
add $4, %sp

# convert arbitrary value to ascii code
push byte(%bp) # number to be converted to ascii code
call convertHexNibble
add $2, %sp
# ax returned by subroutine
push %ax # already an ascii code
push $0xe3
call displayChar
add $4, %sp #clear 2 parameters that we pushed (2 bytes each)
pop %bp # restores the callers stack frame
ret
. = writeHexByte + 512

# Sector 5
convertHexNibble: 
.equ register, 4
push %bp
mov %sp, %bp #sets up stack frame
    cmpb $10, register(%bp)
    jl 1f
    # process here is >=10
    add $0x37, register(%bp)
    jmp 2f  
    # process here is <=10
    1:
    add $0x30, register(%bp)    
    2:
    # expect the register to now be the ascii code
    # to return a value, put it it
    mov register(%bp), %al
    pop %bp # restores the callers stack frame
ret
. = convertHexNibble + 512
```

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is. Load the two sectors you need, then loop through the machine code of the functions passing each byte to the `writeHexByte`.

Comment: @jester how do load sectors. but my question was what the line to create subroutine  in the writeHexBytes to display 2 of the other subroutines machine code.

Comment: how do i load sectors and then loop through machine code of the function passing each byte to the writeHexByte ?